# need assistance with a input issue in java

Tags: java, variables, input

**My Task:**

Create a class called Icosahedron which will be used to represent a regular icosahedron, that is a convex polyhedron with 20 equilateral triangles as faces. The class should have the following features:

- A private instance variable, **edge**, of type **double**, that holds the
  edge
  length.
- A private static variable, **count**, of type **int**, that holds the
  number of Icosahedron objects that have been created.
- A constructor that takes one **double** argument which specifies the edge length.
- An
  instance method **surface()** which returns the surface area of the
  icosahedron. This can be calculated using the formula **5*√3 edge².**
- An
  instance method **volume()** which returns the volume of the icosahedron.
  This can be calculated using the formula **5*(3+√5)/12*edge³**.
- An
  instance method **toString()** which returns a string with the edge
  length, surface area and volume as in the example below:

  `Icosahedron[edge= 3.000, surface=  77.942, volume=  58.906]`

The numbers in this string should be in floating point format with a field
 that is (at least) **7 characters wide** and showing **3 decimal places**.

Please use the static method **String.format** with a suitable formatting
 string to achieve this. A static method **getCount()** which returns the
 value of the static variable count.

Finally, add the following main method to your Icosahedron class so that it can be run and tested:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Number of Icosahedron objects created: " + getCount());
  Icosahedron[] icos = new Icosahedron[4];
  for (int i = 0; i < icos.length; i++)
    icos[i] = new Icosahedron(i+1);
  for (int i = 0; i < icos.length; i++)
    System.out.println(icos[i]);
  System.out.println("Number of Icosahedron objects created: " + getCount());
}
```

Okay. so heres what i have started on:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Icosahedron {
    private double edge = 0;
    private int count = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double useredge = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter Edge Length: ");

}
```

i receive an error on the last line. i cant use println() what am i doing wrong? or maybe im understanding the question wrong? any guidance would be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: It's because you're using System.out.println(...) inside a class instead of a method, I'll answer in a sec if you can't figure it out :)

Comment: You can't use println statement inside the class definition. it must be in methods

Comment: @TwiN: let's avoid answering obvious duplicates.

Comment: Babz: this is Java at its most basic suggesting that you will want to study the intro to Java tutorials and your text book. . You can find the tutorials here: [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Icosahedron class should look like the following:

```
public class Icosahedron {

    private double edge;
    private int count;

    public Icosahedron(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public double getEdge() {
        return edge;
    }

    public void setEdge(double edge) {
        this.edge = edge;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Icosahedron{edge=" + edge + ", count=" + count + '}';
    }

}
```

And your class containing the `main` method (I called it `MoreProblem`):

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class MoreProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Icosahedron[] icos = new Icosahedron[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < icos.length; i++) {
            icos[i] = new Icosahedron(i+1);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Edge Length: ");
            double userEdge = input.nextDouble();
            icos[i].setEdge(userEdge);
        }

        for (Icosahedron icosahedron : icos) {
            System.out.println(icosahedron);
        }

        System.out.println("Number of Icosahedron objects created: " + icos.length);
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you very much